# (Different, read full question) Redirect all urls to one in Apache (Termux)

Tags: apache, redirect

This doesn't seem to be a duplicate, read to know why

I will post what I have done from beginning, maybe I have done something wrong

I have installed apache2 on termux
I have added configured a wlan1 address, which is 1.1.1.1 by executing the following cmd in Termux

```
su -c ip address add 1.1.1.1 -dev wlan1
```

now I can host apache on 1.1.1.1 which makes my server accessible through anyone who connects to my hotspot if I open it, it even works without opening the hotspot
(note, everytime I restart device I must add ip again)

Device: Samsung Galaxy A10
Android Version: Android 13 ARM64 AOSP-ROM

the problem is I'm trying to redirect users who are connected to my network (my hotspot) when I type any url in the search bar, and even Google searches.

now back to my problem, I have made a .htaccess file in the ServerRoot of apache (which is the usr folder) and I have pasted the following code in it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I have tried some other different codes I found online, ended up only working if I enter the server IP and port first, like this

http://1.1.1.1:1111/TEXT

(successfully redirected to http://example.com)

and when I type literally any other url

(not redirected to http://example.com) but that's what I wanna do.

so I do think that it is impossible without entering the IP first, or is it possible?